# Prove the function is strictly increasing or decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $f:(a,b) \rightarrow R$ is differentiable and $f'(x)$ is not $0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.
I need to show that f is strictly increasing or decreasing.It seems trivial to me so I think I am missing something.
Since $f'$ is not $0$, it either greater than or less than 0. Then by the theorem $f$ is monotone increasing or decreasing.
Then it is proved.
Am I right? or did I miss something?

## improvement

I think what I mentioned above does not prove strictness. Can I show strictness by saying $f$ is $g - h$ and $f'$ is $(g -h)'$ then since $f'$ is not $0$, $g$ is not $h$. So we can drop equality.

## I now see where I am being dumb.

Comment: Why would $f'$ have be either greater or less than $0$? Note that it is not assumed that $f'$ is continuous, so you cannot directly use familiar properties of continuous functions like the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: It is differentiable, but $f'$ does not neet to be continuous.

Comment: I am reading baby Rudin and it said that if $f'$ differentiable and greater than or equal to $0$, then $f$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: I want to show that $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing not $f'$. I think $f$ is continuous since $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: You are confusing $f$ and $f'$ here. Surely $f$ is continuous, but that does not really help you in making sure that $f'$ does not change sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a theorem, one could think that $f'(x)$ could jump from positive to negative (or the reverse) in the interval $(a,b)$ without ever becoming zero. After all, it is true that we do not know that $f'(x)$ is continuous, so the Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions does not apply.

However, we do have an Intermediate Value Theorem for derivatives, also called [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)). Refer to that theorem and your problem becomes easy.3

**ADDED:**

Let $c=\frac{a+b}2$ and $a<x<b$. If $f'(x)$ has the opposite sign of $f'(c)$ then by Darboux's theorem $f'(d)=0$ for some $d$ between $c$ and $x$. This contradicts the hypothesis, and since $f'(x)$ cannot be zero, $f'(x)$ has the same sign as $f'(c)$. This is for any $x$, so $f'(x)$ is either all positive or all negative. Without loss of generality, let's say $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Take $x<y$ in $(a,b)$. By the Mean Value Theorem,

$$f'(e)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

for some $e$ such that $x<e<y$. By hypotheses, both the left hand side and the denominator on the right hand side are positive. Therefore, $f(y)-f(x)$ is positive, thus

$$f(x)<f(y)$$

This was for any $x$ and $y$ such that $a<x<y<b$. This is the very definition of "$f$ is monotonic increasing in $(a,b)$". Similarly, if $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ then $f$ is monotonic decreasing in $(a,b)$. Either way, $f$ is monotonic.

There is no need for "tak[ing] a smaller interval."

Comment: Then I find $k$ and $f(x)=k$and using $x$ I take smaller interval and finally I can conclude it is increasing or decreasing oneway?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Check out the [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$